# Installing iPhone app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5, ipad-2, provisioning-profile

I want to install my iphone app on iphone and also have test provisional profile also. The main problem is that i developing applicaion in mac lion environment Xcode version is 4.2.1
and using iOS5 i want to install it on device iPad 4.3.1 (iOS 4) so it gave me error message on Xcode

> The run destination iOS Device is not valid for Running the scheme 'myProjectName The scheme 'myProjectName' contains no buildables that can be built for the SDKs supported by the run destination iOS Device. Make sure your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of Xcode."

What should i have to do for it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are using iOS 5 as your deployment target. Go to build setting and set the deployment target as per your need.

Comment: may i know what do you mean by iOS version? where are you changing it?

Comment: i set my deployment target for 4.0 for release.

Comment: set it with 4.0 for debug option.

Answer (score 0):

In your project settings check for the valid architectures. You need to include both armv6 and armv7 architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Targeted Device Family and make sure the device your distributing to is included in the settings

Answer (score 0):

Please check it with setting  deployment target.